# Regex - Identify Fractions

Tags: php, regex, fractions

I need to identify a fraction from a form field in a recipe database using a Regex. 
Ingredients will be entered in a two part form fields. Field one is the amount, Field two is the ingredient. I then need to break field one into its fractional components to input into the database.

Possible entries include:
1, 1/2, 1 1/2, and any of the previous with words attached such as 1 cup, or 1/2 tbsp.
the hardest I foresee would be: [2 28 oz. cans] where 2 is the number, and 28 oz. cans would be the word.

I have found:
(\b[0-9]{1,3}(?:,?[0-9]{3})*(?:.[0-9]{2})?\b)
which sort of works. I am completely new to Regex, so I am working on guess and check only, and I am having a hard time making it work for me.

Problem #1: I need to identify the word part as well. The word part can be multiple words as well, such as 2 large cans, where large cans would be the word part. The above Regex identifies the numbers very well, but I cant figure out a way to grab the rest of the form field. For example 1 1/2 tbsp gives me 1,1,2 but that is all, and I need tbsp as well. I tried to use this Regex and use len to cut the original down, subtracting the fraction off the front, but had problems since 1 / 2 and 1/2 are both allowed, so cant figure out how many spots to subtract (1 / 2 should subtract 6 from the front of the string, 1/2 should subtract 4 from the front of the string, and just looking at the regex results of 1,2 I cant tell howmany to subtract).

Problem #2: This isnt so important, but any ideas on how to identity the [2 28 oz cans] problem? The above Regex pulls 2,28 out which is not correct, it shoudl only pull 2 out and then the rest (28 oz cans) would be the other part that the solution to problem 1 will hopefully find.

Comment: Why is `2 28 oz. cans` difficult to extract data from if the `2` and the `28 oz. cans` are in separate form fields?

Comment: This sounds like a miserable problem to solve. For my own recipes I just write everything down in decimal in the first place; `.5 cups`. Can you give a _select_ box that pre-populates `1`, `1/2`, `1/3`, `2/3`, `1/4`, `3/4`, `1/5`... for the fractional choices? Sure, someone might know their measurements as `4/3 cups flour`, but handling all these ambiguous inputs sounds rife for trouble.

Comment: So the original idea was use 3 fields. Field 1 is the number, field 2 is the unit, field 3 is the ingredient (so an entry would be: 1 1/2, tbsp., flour). It worked! It was a pain though, and would be so much simpler to just use two fields, one that combines the number and unit (and in the code I would split the number from the unit) and the other field is the ingredient

Comment: oh, with the fraction number I used preg_split on " " and "/" and then used switch statements on how many results to enter into my database a numerator and denominator in improper fraction form

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a regex that will match mixed numbers, whole numbers, and the rest of the entry (the ingredient, hopefully with any extraneous numbers):

```
^((\d+( \d+/\d+)?)|(\d+/\d+))( (.+))?$
```

So for example if had `2 28 ounce cans` it would match:

```
group 1: 2
group 2: 2
group 3: 
group 4: 
group 5:  28 ounce cans
group 5: 28 ounce cans
```

The groups you care about are 1 & 5. **Group 1** will always contain the amount (as a number, fraction, or number with a fraction) and **group 6** will always have the remaining text (the ingredient).

Comment: adding (?:) to groups excludes them from capture

Comment: That was to match the fractional part of a mixed number. As it is the entire number that we care about, that group doesn't matter. Only 1 & 5 do.

Comment: Getting close! only problem is it ignores numbers only. For example someone could enter 2 in the amount field, and eggs in the ingredient field

Comment: @user1008960 If they are in two separate fields, why do you need to separate them with regex? (I've updated so the remaining text is optional, allowing for just numbers or fractions)

Comment: ^((\d+( \d+\/\d+)?)|(\d+\/\d+))\s?(.+)?$ - I think this works? I think space needs to be optional too? Field one: amount (number and or text that can include things like cups) Field two: ingredients (like eggs, milk...). I would love to make it one field, but I dont think that would be possible.

Comment: That one might match a space, but not he remaining text. The updated one I included will match the remaining text offset by a space (but only if that space exists)

Comment: It might work. However, if there is no space then it would match `228 oz cans`. How can you differentiate between whether you meant 228 oz can or 2 28 ounce cans or 22 8 oz cans? The space should be required.

Comment: "The space should be required." I missunderstood your edit, I thought the space was between like this: ^((\d+( \d+/\d+)?)|(\d+/\d+)) ((.+))?$. I copied it wrong. Like this "1/2" isnt found since it doesnt have a space at the end.